# Error en multiplicacion (java)

Tags: java, array

Soy principiante en formación. Intento un código que:

- Solicite número de 4 cifras
- Multiplique cada cifra por la cifra de la misma posición de un array.
  Ejemplo: array  (1,2,4,8)
  numero introducido = 5698
  Resultado a devolver: "117  (1*5+2*6+4*9+8*8)"
  He convertido el String introducido en un array Char.
  Para ver donde falla he preparado para que devuelva lo que encuentra en ambos arrays y el resultado de la multiplicación.
  Sin embargo, esto es lo que me devuelve:

  "5x1=53
  6x2=108
  9x4=228
  8x8=448"

Veo que los datos los extrae bien de cada array, pero al multiplicar no lo hace correctamente. Entiendo que es un problema de tipo de datos, pero no doy con cómo hacerlo.

Muchas gracias.

```
int [] numeSerie={1,2,4,8};
String ent=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce número: ")
char[] entid=ent.toCharArray();
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){     
System.out.println(entid[i]+"x"+numeSerie[i]+"="+entid[i]*numeSerie[i]);
}
```

Comment: Revisa bien que me parece que tu explicación está mal y estás confundiendo al lector

Comment: Editado...espero que ahora se entienda mejor. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de [Character.getNumeric.value()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) para hacer un cast de `char` to `int` de esa manera no obtendras valores incorrectos como te lo detallaron en la otra respuesta, adicional haciendo uso de una variable puedes sumar los valores de los valores multiplicados

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
int suma=0;
int [] numeSerie={1,2,4,8};
String ent=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce número: ");
char[] entid=ent.toCharArray();
for (int i=0;i<numeSerie.length;i++){     
System.out.println(entid[i]+"x"+numeSerie[i]+"="+Character.getNumericValue(entid[i])*numeSerie[i]);
suma+=Character.getNumericValue(entid[i])*numeSerie[i];
} 

System.out.println(suma);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Asi como creas tu variable numeSerie como arreglo de int, asi debes crear la variable entid.

```
int[] entid
```

Si multiplicas un entero con un `char` en realidad estas multiplicando un entero contra la representacion de entero de un caracter.

Si un valor `Char` lo pasas a numero entero como es en este caso el caracter "5" (que para eso es el `Char`) en valor entero va a ser 53 (teclea en un editor de texto o bloc de notas <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> y veras que lo que escribe es el número 5 )
Te dejo un enlace con [la tabla ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora entiendo porqué salen esos números! Pero me queda la duda de como guardo el input del JOptionPane en una matriz int, de forma que cada digito sea una posición en el array. Gracias!!